# Resizing a stage with css height and width

Tags: javascript, css, kineticjs

I want to work with kineticJS on a display area that is defined (height and width) in two ways :

-In my javascript, I want to have arbitrary dimensions to work with, place items, etc.
-In my CSS, I want other dimensions, independantly of the JS one, representing the real display.

There are several advantages to this : JS dimensions can be smaller than the real display, to make computing lighter ; or CSS dimensions can be adapted to the user screen dimensions easely, without impact on the scripting part...

This is easy to do in vanilla JS, using attributes height and width of the canvas for the JS dimensions, and CSS height and width for the display dimensions.

HTML:

```
<canvas height="10" width="10" id="c"></canvas>
```

CSS:

```
#c {
        height:400px;
        width:400px;
    }
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/5fW8f/2/

But with KineticJS, I'm curently unable to do the same thing. When I do this width the container, the container itself is sizing as well, but Stage is not (using dimensions of the stage of or the container).

HTML :

```
<div height="100" width="100" id="c"></div>
```

Same CSS.

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/46JCa/

So, is there a way to do it with KineticJS ?

Comment: If it is easy to do with vanila js why don't you do that?

Comment: Because I want to work with KineticJS, hey.

Comment: OK then. If that's what you want i can't stop you.

Comment: It provides a lot of great features, and there is probably a way.

Comment: I think I was trying to do the same thing as you: work with one set of dimensions for my application (in my case, a game) and then scale them to a screen fitted to the browser viewport. Here's my implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24411850/1093087. Not quite as trivial, perhaps, as you hoped. And I leaned on jQuery. But if I understand your requirements correctly, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is

```
stage.setScale(scale);
```

Where scale is the ratio you want to scale everything by.  Thus you need only calculate it once, set it, and you're done (unless you're using multiple stages; then you'd want to set all of them).

For an example, see http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-multi-touch-scale-stage-with-kineticjs/

It's fast and I use this trick frequently.  You can actually scale any object independently, if you want, or when drawing directly on the canvas.

Comment: It does not work exactly the way I would like, but I think this is the best. Curently, I've manually change the css style of all canvas created, but this is not as clean I suppose.